# Remove height in DOM while using jQueryUI resizable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm using `flex` to make a responsive layout for my web-app.

I'm using jQuery UI on my navigator panel to be able to resize it. Unfortunately, when the resize event is triggered, jQuery UI inserts in the DOM a hard-coded height for my element, even if I specify the handles in the resizable settings.

Here's what I get in the DOM when the resize event is triggered:

```
<div class="navigator ui-resizable" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 245px; height: 929px;">
```

I want to get rid of all the the other styles except the `width`.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>

        html, body {
            margin: 0;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .mainWrapper_1
        {
          display: flex;
          backgound: gold;
          height:100%;
        }

        .mainWrapper_1 .navigatorManager
        {
            background: tomato;
            flex: 0 0 30px;
        }

        .mainWrapper_1 .mainWrapper_2
        {
          background: gray;  
          flex: 1;
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
        }

        .topSideBar
        {
            height:50px;
            background: yellow;
        }
        .mainWrapper_3
        {
            flex: 1;
            background: cyan;
            display:flex;
        }
        .navigator
        {
            flex: 0 0 auto/*100px*/;
            background-color: green;
        }
        .mainWrapper_4
        {
            flex: 1;
            display:flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            background: red;
        }
        .tabs
        {
            height:50px;
            background: pink;
        }
        .mainWrapper_5
        {
            flex: 1;
            background: magenta;
        }

        </style>
    </head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">
    <body>
        <div class="mainWrapper_1">
          <div class="navigatorManager">side</div>
          <div class="mainWrapper_2">
            <div class="topSideBar">
              top side bar
            </div>
            <div class="mainWrapper_3">
                <div class="navigator">
                    navigator
                </div>
                <div class="mainWrapper_4">
                    <div class="tabs">
                        TABS
                    </div>
                    <div class="mainWrapper_5">
                        MAIN
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".navigator").resizable({handles: "e"});
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing only the `height` attribute, the other attributes: `top` and `left` are responsible for positioning the `.navigator` and is probably essential for the resize feature to function. To remove an attribute you can try `removeAttr()` jQuery method or `.removeAttribute()` JavaScript method. The example below is using `.removeAttr()` and has `.removeAttribute()` commented out. If you prefer the latter just swap the comment marks to the other line.

BTW, your code had some weird placements like...

- ...the `<script>` tags being placed **after** the closing `</body>` tag.

  - > `<script>` tags should either be situated at the `<head>` after `<link>` and `<style>` tags.
    >   OR
    >   `<script>` tags can be placed before the closing `</body>` tag.
- Also there was a `<link>` tag **outside** of the `<head>`.

  - > Although I believe it's ok to place a `<link>` tag outside of the head, it should be in the most possibly highest position possible (i.e. the head under any `<meta>` tags.). This is because the browser will render styles as they discovered along the way and you want the DOM finished as early as possible.

    ```
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $(".navigator").resizable({
               handles: "e"
          }).removeAttr('height');
        //document.querySelector('.navigator').removeAttribute('height');
     });
    ```

Live Demo: <kbd>[**PLUNKER**](http://embed.plnkr.co/oT12kMOmgBWXEAxQdVpx/)</kbd>

#### SNIPPET

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/dark-hive/jquery-ui.css">
        <style>
html, body { margin: 0; height: 100%; }
.extLayer { display: flex; backgound: gold; height: 100%; }
.extLayer .navMgr { background: tomato; flex: 0 0 30px; }
.extLayer .endoLayer { background: gray; flex: 1; display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
.topSideBar { height: 50px; background: yellow; }
.intLayer { flex: 1; background: cyan; display: flex; }
.navigator { flex: 0 0 auto/*100px*/; background-color: green; }
.auxLayer { flex: 1; display: flex; flex-direction: column; background: red; }
.tabs { height: 50px; background: pink; }
.coreLayer { flex: 1; background: magenta; }
</style>
        </head>

        <body>
<div class="extLayer">
          <nav class="navMgr">side</nav>
          <div class="endoLayer">
    <header class="topSideBar"> top side bar </header>
    <div class="intLayer">
              <nav class="navigator"> navigator </nav>
              <section class="auxLayer">
        <div class="tabs"> TABS </div>
        <main class="coreLayer">
                  MAIN
                </main>
      </section>
            </div>
  </div>
        </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".navigator").resizable({handles: "e"}).removeAttr('height');
      //document.querySelector('.navigator').removeAttribute('height');
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just solve it also by adding a css rule on the navigator. I added `height: inherit !important;` on it. What do you think is better?

Comment: If you use `.css` and `!important` it might limit your styling options should another plugin need to access that particular style on `.navigator`. `!important` should be used very sparingly. If you remove an inline style like the demo, then your other styles and any future needs at accessing that style is unhindered.

Comment: It worked, nice hack! I found it better than the CSS style hack.

Comment: That's excellent! Btw, if you ever run into a situation when you need to use !important, try using a double class selector instead. Ex. instead of `.exampleClass { height: 500px !important}` , use this `.exampleClass.exampleClass { height: 500px;}` notice that the selector repeats the class. By doing this, that particular selector has a very high specificity that will override almost anything else yet it's not as final as !important is.